# Cannot create layout compatibility with different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, screen, compatibility

I'm trying to create the screens variations for give my app compatibility with most devices. I have created all the screen layouts for the main activity: landscape, w320, w400, w480, w600, w720.

But when I try to create the screen for another activity in Orientation for preview/ Create other...I have the following message:    /Users/user/Desktop/Project/app/src/main/res/layout-w320dp already exists. Use a different qualifier/

Comment: When I choose a different name I can't press OK button, nothing happens and it doesn't create the screen

Comment: Solved: place the second layout manually in the same directory layout-w320dp